# Docker daemon unable to find the dockerfile

Tags: node.js, image, docker

I am trying to create a node-js base image by using the following docker file

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:0.10-onbuild
# replace this with your application's default port
EXPOSE 8888
```

I then run the command " `sudo docker build -t nodejs-base-image .`"
This keeps failing with the error

```
FATA[0000] The Dockerfile (Dockerfile) must be within the build context (.)
```

I am running the above command from the same directory where the 'Dockerfile' is located. What might be going on?
I am on `Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2`

Comment: Your `FROM node:0.10-onbuild` means that a docker image, either local or in a Docker Hub, exists with this name.  Does `docker image | grep node` shows it? Or there is a typo, and you want to use a `ONBUILD` instruction in your Dockerfile? See the doc for ONBUILD at https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#onbuild

Comment: Is there a file named`Dockerfile` in your current directory? Is your local directory accessible to the `root` user?  That is, does `sudo cat Dockerfile` work, or return an error?

Comment: Yes there is a file named Dockerfile and cat Dockerfile works

Comment: I changed the docker file to build from a base image "ubuntu:14.04" which exists in teh local repo. But still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because I did not have appropriate permissions to the Dockerfile in question